# Getting elements of a list in R

Tags: r, list

This is my problem:

There is a predefined list named `gamma` with three entries: `gamma$'2'` is 2x2 matrix `gamma$'3'` a 3x3 matrix and `gamma$'4'` a 4x4 matrix. I would like to have function that returns the matrix I need:

```
GiveMatrix <- function(n) {
    gamma.list <- #init the list of matrices

    gamma.list$n  # return the list entry named n
```

Since `n` is not a character, the last line does not work. I tried `gamma.list$paste(n)`and `gamma.list$as.character(n)`but both did not work. Is there a function that converts `n`to the right format? Or is there maybe a much better way? I know, I am not really good in R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use:

```
gamma.list[[as.character(n)]]
```

In your example, R is looking for a entry in the list called `n`. When using `[[`, the contents of `n` is used, which is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I've found it!

`gamma.list[as.character(n)]` is the solution I needed.

Comment: This will return a list of 1 with a matrix in it, not a matrix.

Comment: If you want the contents of that list element, and not a new list, use `[[` in stead of `[`.

Comment: `[[` and `[` return exactly the same.